# I couldn't get insert data to firestore database using nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to insert data as array using node js but then displayed me this error. I added model class .I implemented model class as class components

controller code

```
const addAnswer = async (req, res, next) => {
    
    const questionName = req.body.questionName;
    const answerName = req.body.answerName;


    const newDetails = new Details({
        //initializing properties
        questionName,
   
        answerName
      })

    newDetails.save().then(() => {
    //saving the object to the db 
     firestore.collection('answersdas').doc().set();
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "New answer Added" })//success message
  }).catch((error) => {
    //error message
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: "Adding answer failed", error: error.message })
  })
}
```

model

```
class Answer {
    constructor(ans) {
        
            this.ans = ans;
              
   
}

module.exports = Answer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is how you can insert the data in given table in Firestore:**

```
const FS_OBJ = {
    projectId: FS_PROJECT_ID,
    privateKey: PRIVATE_KEY,
    clientEmail: CLIENT_EMAIL
}


module.exports = async function writeDataByKey(db, toTable, key, data) {
    const res = await db.collection(toTable).doc(key).set(data);
    return res;
}


app.post('/write-data-by-key', async (req, res) => {
    fireStore.initializeApp({
        credential: fireStore.credential.cert(FS_OBJ)
    });

    const db = fireStore.firestore();
    const { toTable, key, data } = req.body;
    try {
        writeDataByKey(db, toTable, key, data)
            .then((data) => {
                return res.send(data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('getDataByKey: Error in fetching data:', err);
                res.send(err);
            });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log({ message: 'getDataByKey : Something went wrong in reading data', error: error });
        res.send({ message: 'getDataByKey: Something went wrong in reading data', error: error });
    };
});
```